# Drone Unique Identifier - Mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

When Using the DJI Mobile SDK Is there a way to unique identify the drone instance? Maybe a serial or similar that I can access from code?

In the DJI GoApp I can see in the About Tab Info the FlightController serial number - Should I use that?

getSerialNumber(DJICompletionCallbackWith callback) 
Get the serial number of the component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Flightcontroller serial number is definitely a way to uniquely identify the drone.

Use `getSerialNumber` method on FlightController object to get its serial number.